# Macro vba code to find workbooks with connection

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection, connection-string, sqlcommand

I'm trying to scan folders and subfolders for workbooks that have connection strings and sql commands in them but I can't figure out how to do it. The code below is what I have (so far) and I'm stuck. I am very new to macros so I don't know if I'm doing it right. Basically the column headings that I want in my new workbook is the File Path, the Connection String, and the SQL Command. The connection string and SQL Command can be found under Data -> Connections. Right now the code below doesn't write anything so when you run it, it'll open a new workbook but without anything in it. Help me please. :(

```
Sub ReadDataFromAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim FolderName As String ' folder name
    Dim wbName As String ' full name of folder and workbook.
    Dim r As Long 'row number counter
    ' Dim cValue As Variant ' not needed
    Dim wbList() As String 'list of excel workbooks
    Dim wbCount As Integer 'number of excel workbooks
    Dim i, j As Integer 'counters

    ' Start Folder
    FolderName = "C:\Users\lchua\"
    ' create list of workbooks in foldername and put them in the spreadsheet
    wbCount = 0
    wbName = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls") 'I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO IT IN SUBDIRECTORIES :(    
    While wbName <> ""  'Create list of files and directories
        wbCount = wbCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve wbList(1 To wbCount)
        wbList(wbCount) = FolderName & wbName
        wbName = Dir
    Wend

    If wbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    r = 0
    Workbooks.Add ' Creates a new workbook to put data into
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' turn off the screen updating
    For i = 1 To wbCount
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbList(i), True, True)
        If wb.Connections.Count > 0 Then
            numconnections = wb.Connections.Count
            For j = 1 To numconnections
            ' read information into spreadsheet
                Query = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(j).ODBCConnection.CommandText
                ConnectionString = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(j).ODBCConnection.Connection
            Next j
        End If
        wb.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving any changes
        Set wb = Nothing ' free memory
'        r = r + 1
'        cValue = GetInfoFromClosedFile(FolderName, wbList(i), "Sheet1", "A1")
'        Cells(r, 1).Formula = wbList(i)
'        Cells(r, 2).Formula = cValue
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: With what you want to achieve, you are better off using `FileSystemObject` (FSO) or mix of FSO and Dir instead of `Dir` only for the recursive file searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe after this you will love VBA.

With what you want to achieve, there will be 4 parts (Subs):

1. A Sub to list all **Connection** and **CommandText** of a Workbook (if any)
2. A Sub to get name of all Excel files in a folder
3. A Sub to recurse above to every Sub Folder
4. A main Sub to initiate above

Consider my code below:

```
Private Const FILE_FILTER = "*.xl*"
Private Const sRootFDR = "C:\Users\lchua\" ' Root Folder

Private oFSO As Object ' For FileSystemObject
Private oRng As Range, N As Long ' Range object and Counter

Sub Main()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    N = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents ' Remove previous contents
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Filename", "Connections", "Connection String", "Command Text")
        Set oRng = .Range("A2") ' Initial Cell to start storing results
    End With
    ListFolder sRootFDR
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    MsgBox N & " Excel files has been checked for connections."
End Sub

Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)
    Dim oFDR As Object
    ' List the files of this Directory
    ListFiles sFDR, FILE_FILTER
    ' Recurse into each Sub Folder
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ListFolder oFDR.Path & "\" ' Need '\' to ensure the file filter works
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal sFDR As String, ByVal sFilter As String)
    Dim sItem As String
    sItem = Dir(sFDR & sFilter)
    Do Until sItem = ""
        N = N + 1 ' Increment Counter
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        CheckFileConnections oRng.Value ' Call Sub to Check the Connection settings
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move Range object to next cell below
        sItem = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub CheckFileConnections(ByVal sFile As String)
    Dim oWB As Workbook, oConn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim sConn As String, sCMD As String
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbook: " & sFile
    Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    With oWB
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Connections.Count ' 1 column to right (B)
        For Each oConn In .Connections
            If Len(sConn) > 0 Then sConn = sConn & vbLf
            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sCMD = sCMD & vbLf
            sConn = sConn & oConn.ODBCConnection.Connection
            sCMD = sCMD & oConn.ODBCConnection.CommandText
        Next
        oRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = sConn ' 2 columns to right (C)
        oRng.Offset(0, 3).Value = sCMD ' 3 columns to right (D)
    End With
    oWB.Close False ' Close without saving
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

My test folders does not contain any workbook with connections, so the output is:
[image: Output]

You should change where to store these information according to your Sheet. And you may want to comment out the `MsgBox`. Hopefully it won't Error out on Connection related.

Comment: Thank you so much you are so helpful! However for the Command Text, it shows me another connection string, not sql query. Been trying to figure out why is that. The code looks correct though cause it says .CommandText

Comment: Thank you so much, Patrick. I will take time to study and understand your code. I'm very new to vba. Any tips on how to get good at it? Or do you know a good vba book?

Comment: I don't have any books to refer to, when I want to check on objects, I go to MSDN, [Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392(v=office.14).aspx). You can throw in a lot of other stuff into VBA as well, such as .NET SystemCollections, WshShell,  Objects etc. So, have fun!